# How to turn off/supress PHP Fatal error: Out of memory error

Tags: php, apache, error-log

PHP 7.0, Apache 2.2.
For whole website I have error_reporting(E_ALL);
I want to suppress or turn off **just** "PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory" error. Or at least prevent it going to error_log.

Is it possible? If it is, how?

I know why site is getting this error... And I can't do anything about it until admin installs ip-tables or somehow filter out flood requests.

Comment: Just turn off error_reporting? It will still go to log, but not show up on the site.

Comment: set memory limit higher `ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');`, but better lookup why you get that error in the first place

Comment: @JOUM As said before... I know why. There is not bug. Site is under attack for months....

Comment: `Fatal error`s can not be catched

Comment: Log it but don't show it. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` Upon fatal error the page will simply show nothing.

Comment: The page cant continue to render upon a fatal error, because they stop the interpreter.

Comment: No, I am not showing anything! I was asking if I can not log it.